# How to open a new window from the main window in Qt?

Tags: qt, window

I'm new to qt programming and would like to know how to open a new window from the main window with the mainwindow disappearing? Is there any source code I can have a look at?

Comment: You should read Qt documentation first. You are asking questions that are well documented in Qt.

Answer (score 9):

From a slot in your MainWindow call this code :

```
QWidget *wdg = new QWidget;
wdg->show();
hide();//this will disappear main window
```

Comment: it says 'hide' was not declared in this scope

Comment: using [`close();`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close) also works and might be better to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 8):

In `mainwindow.h`

Declare nw object of class NewWindow as below

```
NewWindow *nw = new NewWindow();
```

(Lets say we will open NewWindow, once the button1 is clicked on MainWindow)

Then in `on_pushButton_1_clicked()` slot of class MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked(){ 
    nw->show();
    this->hide();
}
```

Comment: That's correct but it may lead to memory leaks. NewWindow nw; new.show() would be better.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
this-> hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    hide();         // this is to hide the previous window
    secDialog = new SecDialog(this);
    secDialog->show();
```

Make sure to add the first line, hide(); before showing your second dialog so that it can hide your Main Window.