# QT Designer: opening specific window on action

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to QT Designer and would like to open a *specific* window from an action. I've searched and all the examples I've seen are like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988292/how-to-open-a-new-window-from-the-main-window-in-qt) and only give a generic new window, not one that's already predefined. Right now I'm trying to open a predefined window (with header, source, and form) called listcsv right after the file dialog is fulfilled. But the code just makes a generic blank window pop up, not the one I need.

Here's my main window .cpp:

```
#include "csv_helper.h"
#include "ui_csv_helper.h"
#include "listcsv.h"
#include "ui_listcsv.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QWindow>

CSV_helper::CSV_helper(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CSV_helper)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

CSV_helper::~CSV_helper()
{
delete ui;
}

void CSV_helper::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open CSV"),   "/Users/Dropbox", tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"));

    QWidget *listcsv = new QWidget;
    listcsv->show();
    hide();

}
```

I feel frustrated that this is over something so simple, but nothing on the internet seems to give a straight answer.

Edit: Solved, thanks to john elemans. Just had to modify some things.

```
void CSV_helper::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open CSV"), "/Users/Dropbox", tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"));

   ListCSV *msd;
   msd = new ListCSV();

   msd->show();
}
```

Comment: You defined a widget called ListCSV, right? So you should do `auto * myListCSVWidget = new ListCSV();` Or even better without pointers `ListCSV myListCSVWidget;`.

Comment: Checked both of those out. The former gives a warning that auto is a C++11 extension and on run seems to do nothing; the latter gives no warning but does nothing as well.

Comment: Yes, you need to set C++ 11 flags for auto, it doesn't hurt. It also wouldn't hurt to show the code of the widget you are talking about ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your new window's layout in a form file with name to match your dialog.
Create a new C++ class with a  base type of QDialog, called, for example, mySpecialDialog. It should refer the form file as follows;
Private: 
    UI::mySpecialDialog  ui;

Then in your main code, when you want the dialog,...

```
    mySpecialDialog *msd;

    msd = new mySpecialDialog();

    if (msd->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
         ... code 
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

voila.

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify a bit but I got what I needed, see my post above.